# When to initialize data on Flex AIR app Statrup?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I have an AIR app, which keeps its settings stored on the disk.

Now, when the application starts, i need to read these values from the disk file and populate the variables in my ModelLocator. My doubt is where to put this code during the App Lifecycle. I have it currently on `applicationComplete`. Since i am not making any updates to the UI in this code, can i move this initialization code to the 'initialize' event and thereby speed up the startup time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can move it in **initialize** i suggest create *wrapper class*, 
for these properties

by doing this *validation* and other stuff like change in *attribute names* could be easy,

you only needs to change wrapper class and rest of application will remains same

hopes that helps

Comment: thank you @Imran, one question where should i place this wrapper class in relation to my main file. Are you talking about a Utility class with a static method to do this job?

Comment: no i am talking about simple class same as ValueObject "VO", let say it AppPropertiesVO.as, which usually contains getter and setter methods to communicate with App, and put this class reference/object in Model as attribute.